# Asus H310T R2 BIOS update

Tags: bios, motherboard, upgrade, asus

I have a second hand micro-ITX ASUS motherboard PRIME H310T R2 exactly like this one: https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-h310t-r2-0/ It came with BIOS/UEFI version 0303 and I want to upgrade in order to use another processor.

All BIOS available in ASUS website appears as PRIME-H310T-R2-SI platform in EzFlash, but it identifies my motherboard as PRIME-H310T-R2-BR, thus doesn't allow upgrade with error message "Model Name doesn't match!".

I've contact ASUS support, with no success. As I don't have warranty anymore, they recommend me go to third part technical support.

Also, the serial number of the motherboard doesn't appear anywhere. I don't have original box, BIOS/UEFI doesn't show, and I can't find it on Windows/Ubuntu.

There is another program besides EzFlash that could do this upgrade? Can I rename platform in BIOS file? Is there a way to identify its serial number?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
I was able to force update using AFUDOS/AFUWIN with PRIME-H310T-R2-SI-2208 version, but it didn't work well. I boots, but I can't save any setting changes.

Can someone find if ASUS has a regional BR version of H310T R2? Or have I a counterfeit motherboard?

Comment: Try the answers [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ASUS/comments/zkvxo7/help_what_are_meupdatetool_and_management_engine/).

Comment: https://www.asus.com/br/motherboards-components/motherboards/prime/prime-h310m-e-r2-0-br/helpdesk_bios?model2Name=PRIME-H310M-E-R2-0-BR It seems you have a "regional" (BR) variant, the same exact model doesn't appear in other languages. There's only one update available and it says nothing about supporting newer CPUs.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Looks like I have a regional Brazilian motherboard, but the link you sent is for H310M and mine is H310T. I still get "Model Name doesn't match!".

Comment: Good catchT So, this one also from the Brazilian site, albeit not mentioning "BR" at the end like the other did, should be the correct firmware: https://www.asus.com/br/supportonly/prime%20h310t%20r2-0/helpdesk_bios/ . Seems to be the same version number and, again, no mention of supporting newer CPUs, just *Support Windows 11 by default, no settings changes required in the UEFI BIOS.* Probably not helpful for what you want, therefore if you can't update I suggest you keep things as they are.

Comment: @harrymc MEUpdateTool seems to be an option, but the one from H310T R2.0 isn't compatible too: "This tool doesn't support [ PRIME H310T R2.0/BR ] motherboard."

Comment: Seems to me like a bug in the tool, not understanding BR. The BIOS is very likely fully compatible. You need to force the update.

Comment: @ChanganAuto There is a "show all" below BIOS 2208, some older versions are for CPU compatibility. Although is the Brazilian website, all versions are for region "SI".

Comment: Just to caution that forcing a BIOS update is chancy.

Comment: @harrymc How to force an BIOS update? None of the tools gave me this option.

Comment: According to HP you can [update the BIOS from within the BIOS](https://www.hp.com/hk-en/shop/tech-takes/post/how-to-update-bios-software-on-windows-pcs): you spam F10 on boot to get into the BIOS and update from a USB. The instructions require a working Windows computer to prepare the USB. I suggest to check first that your BIOS truly has a USB update option before going this way.